# IE9 css is not aligning menu properly

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-9

I have following html:

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><img src="../Content/themes/base/images/logo.png" /></li>                        
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Songs", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("New", "About", "Home")</li>                    
            </ul>
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="abc.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="light" data-font="arial"></div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

and css:

```
ul#menu {
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    display:inline;
}

ul#menu li {
    display:inline;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li#greeting {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#menu li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;    
    line-height: 2.8em;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;   
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

ul#menu li a:active {
    background-color: #a6e2a6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li.selected a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

This works great in Chrome, on firefox it works good also only the FB like text is not showing that is not big deal. But on IE it is terrible all menu links are on the left on top of each other. I tried many thing but am unable to resolve it. Can anyone please see what am i doing wrong?

[image: How it looks in IE]

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or link to your site so we can view in IE?

Comment: Actually its on my localhost and i am not sure how to make a fiddle can i post a snagit of it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with snagit, but whatever tool you'd like, just so I can view it live in IE.

Comment: @zenkaty - Added the image. All three li itmes are on the left on top of each other. And Fb option is in the middle below the header.

Comment: Ah, I meant a live example, not an image. Go to jsfiddle.net and create a simplified version of your problem code - check it in IE to make sure the problem is still happening, and if it is, post it here. We can then view it and edit it ourselves :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the styling of your `nav` element or `ul` element for wrong positioning or width limitation or margin/padding you don't want.

If you have indeed floated right your anchors, and you also have non-anchors (like the image), you will want to float that image as well to keep it consistent?

On a seperate note, your markup can be very much simplified like:

```
<nav>
  <a href="/html/">HTML</a>
  <a href="/html5/">HTML5</a>
  <a href="/css/">CSS</a>
  <a href="/css3/">CSS3</a>
  <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a>
</nav>
```

*example from www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_nav.asp*